# The results of my functions when I call a spline function gives wrong values

Tags: vba

I have a function that only call the spline function when something happens..in this case when a division is less than zero..the inputs for the function is the same that for the spline function(called CUBIC), the spline was tested and works well when I call it direct! someone can help me?...follows a party of the code

```
   Function NDF6(T As Variant, dias As Variant, taxas As Variant)
     If T <= dias(1) Then
    NDF6 = taxas(1)
    Exit Function
   End If
 If T >= dias(tam) Then
    NDF6 = taxas(tam)
    Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To tam
    If T <= dias(i) Then
        If taxas(i) / taxas(i - 1) < 0 Then
            Call CUBIC(T, dias, taxas)
        Else
            i0 = ((taxas(i - 1) * dias(i - 1)) / 360) + 1
            i1 = ((taxas(i - 1) * dias(i - 1)) / 360) + 1
            irel = i1 / i0
            i2 = irel ^ ((T - dias(i - 1)) / (dias(i) - dias(i - 1)))
            i2rel = i2 * i0
            i2real = i2rel - 1
            NDF6 = i2real * (360 / T)
       End If
 Public Function CUBIC(x As Variant, input_column As Variant, output_column As Variant)
```

Comment: There's not enough info here to really tell what the problem might be.  You need to provide some sample inputs, the "wrong" outputs, and what the expected outputs should be.  And the full code for the CUBIC function.

Comment: @TimWilliams OK!!follows the full code of cubic

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a zero value when I call the cubic function. The inputs are a cell with a value with a value equivalent a day and two arrays(DUONOFF and ONOFF) equivalent a days and rates, I call the function like:

NDF6(512,DUONOFF,ONOFF)

follows the CUBIC function

```
  Public Function CUBIC(x As Variant, input_column As Variant, output_column As Variant)
  'Purpose: Given a data set consisting of a list of x values
 ' and y values, this function will smoothly interpolate
  ' a resulting output (y) value from a given input (x) value

  ' This counts how many points are in "input" and "output" set of data
  Dim input_count As Integer
  Dim output_count As Integer
  input_count = input_column.Rows.Count
   output_count = output_column.Rows.Count
   Next check to be sure that "input" # points = "output" # points
   If input_count <> output_count Then
  CUBIC = "Something's messed up! The number of indeces number of output_columnues don't match!"
  GoTo out
  End If

  ReDim xin(input_count) As Single
  ReDim yin(input_count) As Single
  Dim c As Integer
  For c = 1 To input_count
  xin(c) = input_column(c)
  yin(c) = output_column(c)
  Next c

      values are populated

 Dim N As Integer 'n=input_count
 Dim i, k As Integer 'these are loop counting integers
 Dim p, qn, sig, un As Single
 ReDim u(input_count - 1) As Single
 ReDim yt(input_count) As Single 'these are the 2nd deriv values
 N = input_count
 yt(1) = 0
 u(1) = 0
 For i = 2 To N - 1
 sig = (xin(i) - xin(i - 1)) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i - 1))
 p = sig * yt(i - 1) + 2
 yt(i) = (sig - 1) / p
 u(i) = (yin(i + 1) - yin(i)) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i)) - (yin(i) - yin(i - 1)) / (xin(i) - xin(i -   _1))
  u(i) = (6 * u(i) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i - 1)) - sig * u(i - 1)) / p

  Next i

  qn = 0
  un = 0
  yt(N) = (un - qn * u(N - 1)) / (qn * yt(N - 1) + 1)
  For k = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
      yt(k) = yt(k) * yt(k + 1) + u(k)
         Next k


      now eval spline at one point

     Dim klo, khi As Integer
     Dim h, b, a As Single
      first find correct interval
    klo = 1
    khi = N
    Do
     k = khi - klo
     If xin(k) > x Then
     khi = k
     Else
     klo = k
     End If
     k = khi - klo
     Loop While k > 1
     h = xin(khi) - xin(klo)
     a = (xin(khi) - x) / h
     b = (x - xin(klo)) / h
     y = a * yin(klo) + b * yin(khi) + ((a ^ 3 - a) * yt(klo) + (b ^ 3 - b) * yt(khi)) * (h ^ 2) _/ 6

     CUBIC = y
    out:
     End Function
```